# New iPhone 4S user looking to sync Outlook email

Tags: iphone, email, ms-office, exchange

My IT departmant does not have activesync on our exchange server(nor do they plan to get it any time soon) are their any apps out there that will allow me to connect my iphone 4s and sync my outlook email.  My former phone was a Droid X and I used the touchdown software which worked great.
Thanks, 
Tes

Comment: What version of Exchange do they use?

Comment: Does your employer use OWA (Outlook Web Access), the Exchange webmail interface ?

Answer (score 1):

If they enable IMAP on the Exchange Server (which may have been done already), you can add it as an IMAP mail server on your phone. You won't have push email (as iOS doesn't support IMAP IDLE), but it'll work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using Office Mail from codebeforedawn which privides an app frontend to Outlook Web Access. I am fairly happy with this and it wasn't too expensive. Otherwise you might be able to use IMAP as detailed in the answer from mjturner.